# MxPlayer how create playList

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried create video playlist using MX Player but I have a little problem.
The first video played well but when his finishing is not transferred to the next.

The developer of MX Player documented i found here: https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/api

My code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

ArrayList<Uri> pack = new ArrayList<Uri>();
pack.add((Uri.parse("http://mysite/file1.mp4")
pack.add((Uri.parse("http://mysite/file2.mp4")
pack.add((Uri.parse("http://mysite/file3.mp4")
i.setDataAndType(paczek.get(0), "video/*");

i.putExtra( EXTRA_VIDEO_LIST, new Parcelable[] { pack.get(0),  pack.get(1), pack.get(2)} );
...
  Try-catch   
    startActivityForResult( i, 0 );
```

Would the creation of playlists is possible or should I catch end of the film on onActivityResult and start next Intent?

Comment: Could you pass playlist to mxplayer?